# String concatenation in where clause

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I posted the following question yesterday: [Multiple 'in' statements in a where clause that need to match against each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721784/multiple-in-statements-in-a-where-clause-that-need-to-match-against-each-other/8721851#8721851)

In this there was some discussion about a feature in Oracle which doesn't exist in Microsoft SQL, the specific line of code being:

```
where (suite_id,lease_id) in (('CCBG08','205059'),('CCBG14','152424'),('CCCF048','150659'))
```

Assuming that we have a table of (however with more rows):

> suite_id  lease_id
>
> CCBG08         150659
>
> CCBG14         152424

I extrapolated on this to create the following solution for Microsoft SQL:

```
select  *
from    property.lease_period
where   (suite_id + ' ' + lease_id) 
        in (
            ('CCBG08 205059'),
            ('CCBG14 152424'),
            ('CCCF048 150659')
        )
```

Unfortunately the performance implications of doing something like this are quite significant (as indexes aren't being used). I was wondering how this could be improved?

Comment: Can you make it a computed column and index that?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx

Comment: @MikeChristensen Potentially, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Probably writing it out the long way is better, like everyone smarter than me has already suggested :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably we are talking about dynamically-generated SQL here, right?  So, in that case, why not just use the long-form:

```
select  *
from    property.lease_period
where
(suite_id = 'CCBG08' AND lease_id = '205059') OR 
(suite_id = 'CCBG14' AND lease_id = '152424') OR 
(suite_id = 'CCCF048' AND lease_id = '150659')
```

*edit*
Re-reading your original thread, I see this is basically what you started with and were hoping to avoid.  Considering that, you could use the method you posted (string concatenated values) with an index by creating a view off of property.lease_period, and include in that view a calculated column (suite_id + ' ' + lease_id as suite_lease - for example).  Finally, create an index for that view on that column.  Then change your code to select from this new view and column, rather than the base table.

Comment: For educations sake how would you accomplish the above whilst still using indexes?

Comment: If your index contains both suite_id and lease_id, then it will be used.

Comment: Doesn't suite_id and lease_id have an index? if not can you create it?

Comment: Sorry, by the above I was referring to the original code in the question. I actually started with what you had here but was hoping to work out how to do this with concatenation for educations sake

Answer (score 4):

I would just bite the bullet and spell out the OR conditions explicitly:

```
SELECT *
    FROM property.lease_period
    WHERE (suite_id = 'CCBG08' AND lease_id = '205059')
       OR (suite_id = 'CCBG14' AND lease_id = '152424')
       OR (suite_id = 'CCCF048' AND lease_id = '150659')
```

Comment: @MattH Well, a minute *and* 24 seconds, but who's counting? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a JOIN onto a temp table/table var, which may be a neater way depending on your scenario/number of combinations:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (suite_id VARCHAR(10), lease_id VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @data VALUES('CCBG08', '205059')
INSERT @data VALUES('CCBG14', '152424')
INSERT @data VALUES('CCCF048', '150659')

select  l.*
from    property.lease_period l
    JOIN @data d ON l.suite_id = d.suite_id AND l.lease_id = d.lease_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget a solution with cte's ;)

```
with cte (suite_id, lease_id)  as (
   select         'CCBG08' , '205059' 
   union  select  'CCBG14'  ,'152424' 
   union  select  'CCCF048' , '150659'
) 
select * 
from cte 
 JOIN property.lease_period l 
   ON l.suite_id = cte.suite_id 
  AND l.lease_id = cte.lease_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert that particular condition of the `WHERE` clause into a join like this:

```
SELECT
…
FROM property.lease_period p
  INNER JOIN (
    VALUES ('CCBG08','205059'), ('CCBG14','152424'), ('CCCF048','150659')
  ) x (suite_id, lease_id)
  ON p.suite_id = x.suite_id AND p.lease_id = x.lease_id
```

Comment: This works for SQL-Server 2008. But still, no `WHERE (x.suite_id,x.lease_id) = (p.suite_id,p.lease_id)` in SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube: No, no tuple comparison, which is a shame. I think I've seen a corresponding request on MS Connect, though I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't what oracle provides just a short form of this?

```
select  *
from    property.lease_period
where   (suite_id = 'CCBG08' and lease_id = '205059') or 
        (suite_id = 'CCBG14' and lease_id = '152424') or
        (suite_id = 'CCCF048' and lease_id = '150659') or
```

Sorry if this isn't quite right, my sql is a little rusty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a lot of point in it (I prefer the top answer which I also upvoted), but since you have asked (for education's sake) for a version using concatenation, the following would be faster than the code in your question as it would utilize the index on one of the columns

```
select  *
from    property.lease_period
where  
      suite_id in ('CCBG08', 'CCBG14', 'CCCF048')
      AND
      (suite_id + ' ' + lease_id) 
        in (
            ('CCBG08 205059'),
            ('CCBG14 152424'),
            ('CCCF048 150659')
        )
```